# Alter markup around a webform

Tags: 7, theming, webforms

I have been trying to alter the markup generated by my webform. [image: example webform].

Example changes which I would like to do:

- Add the class "form-horizontal" to the classes under `<form class=""/>`.
- Add the class "input-xxlarge" to each input field.
- Remove any markup generated by the webform module (e.g. form-item, webform-component, webform-component-textarea).

I've been trying to override these values with the help of Devel. Using `webform-form-[nid].tpl.php`, I have the following line before I make any print statements:

```
$form['#attributes']['class']['0'] = 'form-horizontal';
```

The issue is that I can not alter the form classes. Any insight that can be shared would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [theme_form_element](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_form_element/7) ?

> Returns HTML for a form element.

This hook is used to alter the thme of form element in Drupal.

Check [theme_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/theme_field/7) as well.

[How to theme form element in Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/28786/4471)

Comment: theme_form_element was the key that I was missing. Using this, I was able to add new classes to a field.

Comment: how it is possible in drupal 8